# CSS Image height 100% (auto width) with dynamic text next to it

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to style a section with text on the left side and an image on the right side. This style should be reusable for images with different ratios/formats so setting fixed heights is not an option. The text is also dynamic in length. The image should always fill the full height of the section and its width should scale so the image ratio stays the same.

I already tried finding an solution online and the two best approaches I got are these:

**(1) position absolute + display flex**

The image behaves correct when scaling the browser but because of the **position absolute** the text goes behind the image.

```
<style>
body {
  background-color: red;
}

.box {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.content-wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
}

button {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

img {
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
}
</style>

<div class="box">
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div>
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
      <p>consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <button>Click here</button>
  </div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300.png?text=placeholder+image" alt="">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7tcz2dn4/

**(2) plain display flex**

This solution behaves correct in really wide screen resolutions but in smaller ones a x-axis scrollbar appears.

```
<style>
body {
  background-color: red;
}

.box {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
}

.content-wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

button {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}
</style>

<div class="box">
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div>
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
      <p>consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
    <button>Click here</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300.png?text=placeholder image" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t8o4L29g/

The HTML-structure is not fix so if I need to wrap/unwrap elements to get the desired result that's not a problem. Thank you guys in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For your issue its a good idea to use columns, you can give your left column the text and the right one the image.

When using images here is a tip:

```
<style>
img {
   object-fit: cover;
   object-position: center;
}
</style>
```

When using these stylings to an image you can set a height and width without ruining the image.